# VS Code changing modified file colors in Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not a huge fan of the peach color in the explorer for modified files. Searching through the color theme reference I can't seem to find an override..

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference

I've even tried disabling extensions and I am still seeing those predefined colors.. I am using the Monokai Soda theme but that doesn't seem to be what is setting those colors in the sidebar.. [image]

Any help appreciated - it's kinda driving me crazy..

## ANSWER

Needed a combo of error style and git overrides, see answer below:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.errorForeground": "#b3e5ec",
    "list.warningForeground": "#00d9ff",
    "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#00ffb3",
    "gitDecoration.untrackedResourceForeground": "#f7aeae"
}
```

Comment: thx for "untrackedResourceForeground"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out that the colour you're seeing isn't due to modified content. It's due to having problems/errors in your file. If you hover over the file name you should see `x problems detected in this file`.

To change the colour of those, you can use

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.errorForeground": "#00AA00"
}
```

The colour for modified files looks like the colour that `settings.json` is highlighted in, aka light green.

Comment: Hmmm.. Didn't seem to work even when I specifically switched to the standard Monokai. :(

Comment: @Bess see my updated answer. I managed to reproduce the situation on my machine.

Comment: Ahhhh I had blanked on the linting errors there. Thanks for the tips. Will update my question with my changes!

Comment: @Bess, no problem. Glad you found it useful. :)